# create large number of Thread in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a "log service" as a web service on separate web application. for logging user page visit, i create new Thread and call web service within. in this way end user will not wait for calling "log service" and immediately get response.

what troubles may happen?
what if somebody press "F5" for long time?
what happen if i use Thread Pool?

have you a better idea?

Comment: Could you just call your web service asynchronously? If you can generate client code with async operations, you should be able to call `service.AsyncLog(...)` instead of `service.Log(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new thread for each web service call is not a good practice because creating a new thread is an expensive operation.

Using the ThreadPool is better, because it will reuse existing threads. You could use the [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx) method for this.

I think making an asynchronous call to the web service is the best option here. It depends on the type of web service you are calling. When the web service is a SOAP service you could make use of the asynchronous methods on the generated service reference. Otherwise you could use one of the asynchronous methods on the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class like [WebClient.UploadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144239(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

What could happen is that you crash, deploy or reboot and all outstanding work is lost.

Also, you could consume an unbounded amount of resources. Threads are expensive (1MB of memory). Use the thread-pool, or use async IO or batch calls to the external service.

Also, unhandled exceptions in background threads cause the process to be killed without further notice. You will not be notified of that bug and outstanding/running work is lost.